# Best way to aggregate a set of observations over overlapping time ranges into a time series?

Tags: time-series, data-transformation, overlapping-data

A data manipulation I commonly need to perform involves creating a time series by aggregating a quantity which was sampled over many overlapping time ranges.

For example, consider the following contrived data on movie times and attendance at a movie theater:

```
| Movie ID | Movie Start Time | Movie End Time | Attendance |
|----------+------------------+----------------+------------|
| Movie 1  |             0:00 |           2:00 |         30 |
| Movie 2  |             1:00 |           3:00 |         40 |
```

Treating all time intervals as half-closed on the left, like `[Start time, End time)`, I'd like to compute the total attendance at the theater as a time series, i.e.,

```
| Time | Total Attendance |
|------+------------------|
| 0:00 |               30 |
| 1:00 |               70 |
| 2:00 |               20 |
| 3:00 |                0 |
```

What is this type of manipulation called? Is there a way to do this efficiently, preferably in a Python/pandas environment?

Comment: Have you looked into sessionization techniques.

Comment: If sessionization means grouping discrete user events into a single time range, that's not what I want. My data are already grouped into sessions with start and stop times, and I'd like to find the number of active sessions as a time series. Could sessionization help with that?

Comment: i think the last step should be a groupby time.  The first step might be grouping by movie and resampling at the desired interval (probably a vectorized way to do this).  E.g. For each movie in data resample with forward fill; groupby time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is probably something that would work like 1000 times more pythonic than this solution, but it should get you to where you need to go.

```
import pandas as pd

#Recreating your example data. Note the addition of dates. I'm assuming you really have timestamps in your data.
df=pd.DataFrame()
df['Movie ID']=[1,2]
df['Start']=["06/01/2017 0:00","06/01/2017 1:00"]
df['End']=["06/01/2017 2:00","06/01/2017 3:00"]
df['Attendance']=[30,40]
df['Start']=pd.to_datetime(df['Start'])
df['End']=pd.to_datetime(df['End'])

#This is what actually does what you need it to do.
df1=df.copy()
df2=df.copy()
df1.index=df1['Start']
df2.index=df2['End']
df_final=df1.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('h')).sum()['Attendance'].fillna(0).subtract(df2.groupby(pd.TimeGrouper('h')).sum()['Attendance'].fillna(0),fill_value=0).cumsum()

#Just displaying the resultant dataframe.
print(df_final)
```

The real trick is that for this to work you need to be able to transform your start/end times to actual python datetimes. And the resulting dataframe looks like this:

```
2017-06-01 00:00:00    30.0
2017-06-01 01:00:00    70.0
2017-06-01 02:00:00    40.0
2017-06-01 03:00:00     0.0
Freq: H, Name: Attendance, dtype: float64
```

Comment: Note this code should work for multiple movies starting at the same time, e.g. a third movie that also starts at 1:00 and ends at 3:00. It will also aggregate everthing up to the hour level, so if it starts at 1:15 and ends at 3:30, it will still work.